# Menu icon is not material design with collapseActionView

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-support-library

I'm following the [Adding Search Functionality](https://developer.android.com/training/search/index.html) tutorial.

## With `collapseActionView`:

When I use `collapseActionView|ifRoom` the back behavior is correct, but the search icon isn't material:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

[image: bad icon]
[image: good back]

## Without `collapseActionView`:

If I omit `collapseActionView` the icon looks right, but the back behavior is broken.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
```

[image: good icon]
[image: bad back]

## Questions:

- Why does `collapseActionView` change the search icon style?
- How do I make sure my icons are material?
- Should I be using my own drawables rather than `@android:drawable/...`

## Using:

- compile/target = 25
- minSdk = 14
- Support library = 25.2.0

Comment: You could try using your own icon. Then you'll know. I'm not sure if you're aware but in Android Studio you can download them from the menu (file, new, vector asset). Then click the icon button and choose from a big list. Then reference that in your code. You probably knew this but maybe not if you didn't try it. If this works then problem solved.